# Github Action for Laravel Error when Generating Key

Tags: php, laravel, github-actions

When i create github workflow for my laravel project, it throw error with exit code 255 like this

```
Run php artisan key:generate
  php artisan key:generate
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected identifier "string", expecting variable in /home/runner/work/TukerIn/TukerIn/vendor/sebastian/version/src/Version.php on line 25
Error: Process completed with exit code 255.
```

Is anyone have solution about this?

Comment: Sounds like the command-line version of PHP is running 8.0 or lower. That version of Laravel needs at least PHP 8.1. Line 25 is `private readonly string $version;`, and `readonly` properties were introduced in 8.1

Comment: Ah i see, i solved it by changed the PHP version to 8.2. Thank you @aynber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved,

I changed the PHP Version of the .yaml file to 8.2 when before was 8.0

Thank you @aynber for the solution